# Add Wordpress as subfolder to existing rails site using nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, subdirectory

I have a running app using rails (unicorn) and nginx. My client asked me to move a wordpress blog onto existing server as a subfolder.
Let's assume current site is www.example.com. The blog link should be www.example.com/blog
I do not succeed to configure nginx to server wordpress blog.
My current nginx configuration is:

```
upstream app_server_dinchi {
  server unix:/tmp/.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root /home/ubuntu/websites/example_staging/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server_dinchi;
 }

 #blog configuration
 location /blog {
    root /home/ubuntu/websites/blog.example.com;
    index index.php;
 }

 location ~ /blog/.+\.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME       /home/ubuntu/websites/blog.example.com$fastcgi_script_name;
 }

 location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ {
    if ($query_string ~ "^[0-9]+$") {
      expires max;
      break;
    }
  }

 error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
 location = /500.html {
   root /home/ubuntu/websites/example_staging/current/public;
 }

}
```

When I try to access example.com/blog I receive 404.
Can somebody point to me how to add this subfolder?

Comment: any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're forwarding to @app while it should be @app_server_dinchi